# Adding new row at the end of each column

Tags: excel, vba

I have sheet name called ABC

[image]

I need to add new row at the end of each column value. For example in the column Product ID at the end of 'aaa' and at the end of 'bbb' i need to insert copy of aaa to new row at the end of aaa as well copy of bbb to new row at the end of bbb.

```
Dim cell As Range 
For Each cell In Range("c2:c7") 
  If cell.Value = "aaa" Then 
    cell.EntireRow.Insert 
  End If 
Next cell
```

But it is inserting after `aaa` value found, and I need at the end of `aaa`

Comment: I have sheet name called ABC

Comment: I tried this Dim cell As Range
 
For Each cell In Range("c2::c7")
    If cell.Value = "aaa" Then
        cell.EntireRow.Insert
    End If
Next cell

Comment: but it inserting after aaa value found ,i need at the end of aaa

Answer (score 1):

You were on a very good track, however, there are two changes that need to be implemented to your code.

The first one is making `"aaa"` reference dynamic, i.e. you do not want your code to always look for `"aaa"`, but rather always check the "looped" cell's value.

The second change is the loop itself. As your goal is to insert rows, your table range will expand and thus your loop won't serve its purpose. Instead, you should loop from the **bottom** of the table to the very **top**.

Here's the code for you to test:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim lngRow As Long
    
    With Sheet1
        For lngRow = 10 To 3 Step -1
          If .Range("C" & lngRow).Value <> .Range("C" & lngRow + 1).Value Then
            .Range("C" & lngRow + 1).EntireRow.Insert
            .Range("C" & lngRow + 1).Value = .Range("C" & lngRow).Value
          End If
        Next lngRow
    End With
End Sub
```

Here's the result after running the code:

[image]

Comment: @JvdV ahh it's good to be back! :-) and it's so great to see how much your profile has grown - wow, respect!! I'm quite busy these days with CFA exam preparations and work but I'll try to be more active. Didn't know how much I missed it until I started checking the posts again. I hope you're ok!

Comment: Haha couldn't explain it better. Each question is like a good brain teaser. I'll definitely see you around! :-)